# how to use variable value within the javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to print my product details when i click on button.
I have two dictionaries **watches** and **Tv**
 here is my javascript code in this i use `show(btn)` function to print values of dictionary and `btn` saves name of the dictionary. But when i write `btn["name"]` output is undefined.
but when I click on watches button and `alert(btn)` it gives me output as watches or I click on Tv button and `alert(btn)` it gives me output as Tv.
Then why `btn["name"]` is not working.

```js
var watches = {
    name : "Titan",
    price: "8,999",
    country : "Indian"
}
var Tv = {
    name : "Mi Tv",
    price: "20,999",
    country : "China"
}

function show(btn){
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = btn["name"];
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = btn["price"];
        document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = btn["country"];
}
var j = document.querySelectorAll(".product").length;

for(var i=0; i<j; i++){
document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    var btn = this.innerHTML;
    show(btn);
});
 
}
```

```css
table,th,td{
    border:2px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<button class="product">watches</button>
<button class="product">Tv</button>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name of the Product</th>
        <td id="name">--</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Price</th>
        <td id="price">--</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <td id = "country">--</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` returns a string, it doesn't contain such properties like `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your show function didn't reference the data object properly.
I updated your show function and declare a variable data to reference to data object.

```js
var watches = {
    name : "Titan",
    price: "8,999",
    country : "Indian"
}
var Tv = {
    name : "Mi Tv",
    price: "20,999",
    country : "China"
}

function show(btn){
    var data = (btn ==="watches")? watches :Tv ;
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = data["name"];
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = data["price"];
    document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = data["country"];
}
var j = document.querySelectorAll(".product").length;

for(var i=0; i<j; i++){
  document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    var btn = this.innerHTML;
    show(btn);
  });
 
}
```

Comment: @satyamjha Be careful this is solution will only work if there are just two products. If there are multiple products you need to have a bunch of if else conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take a `String` value and treat it as a variable, what you're passing to the show function is a `String` value which is not at all same as the variables `watches` and `Tv`.

What I would recommend is create an object with `watches` and `Tv` as keys and then you can use the `String` passed to the function to access the particular property on the object.

```js
const products = {
  watches: {
    name: "Titan",
    price: "8,999",
    country: "Indian"
  },
  Tv: {
    name: "Mi Tv",
    price: "20,999",
    country: "China"
  }
}

function show(btn) {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = products[btn]["name"];
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = products[btn]["price"];
  document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = products[btn]["country"];
}
var j = document.querySelectorAll(".product").length;

for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var btn = this.innerHTML;
    console.log(btn);
    show(btn);
  });
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<button class="product">watches</button>
<button class="product">Tv</button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name of the Product</th>
    <td id="name">--</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Price</th>
    <td id="price">--</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <td id="country">--</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```